# Show Procedures/Functions MySQL Command Line

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, command-line, mysql-function

How can I see the list of the stored procedures or stored functions in mysql command line like `SHOW TABLES;` or `SHOW DATABASES;` commands.

Answer (score 785, accepted):

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;
```

Comment: Is there a way to find current stored procedure name? I believe it's `object_name(@@procid) ` in SSMS anything like this in MySql?

Comment: If the user has the privilege of `EXECUTE`, or else, this will show empty list.

Answer (score 223):

```
show procedure status
```

will show you the stored procedures.

```
show create procedure MY_PROC
```

will show you the definition of a procedure. And

```
help show
```

will show you all the available options for the `show` command.

Comment: As Codler pointed out, help show does not work as help is a mysql command line instruction.  To get more info about the SHOW command, go straight to MySQL documentation page at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show.html

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you say that, help show works fine for me using MySQL 5.0.95 on centos 6.3

Comment: It works if you use mysqls own command line client. I don't, so I prefer the online reference.

Answer (score 105):

For view procedure in name wise

```
select name from mysql.proc
```

below code used to list all the procedure and below code is give same result as show procedure status

```
select * from mysql.proc
```

Comment: this is a lot cleaner presentation than the others especially if you are in a smaller terminal.  thanks.

Comment: I evolved this answer into `select db,name,type from mysql.proc where db<>'sys';` for a bit more info, and less built-in system kruft.

Answer (score 54):

A more specific way:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS 
WHERE Db = DATABASE() AND Type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: it'll work without using AND Type = 'PROCEDURE' also,

Comment: The `Type` filter is handy in case you have functions that you not want to see.

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned above,

```
show procedure status;
```

Will indeed show a list of procedures, but shows *all* of them, server-wide.

If you want to see just the ones in a single database, try this:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'databasename';
```

Comment: Likewise, SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'databasename'; gives you the functions.

Answer (score 33):

Alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Answer (score 25):

My preference is for something that:

1. Lists both functions and procedures,
2. Lets me know which are which,
3. Gives the procedures' names and types **and nothing else**,
4. Filters results by the current database, *not the current definer*
5. Sorts the result

Stitching together from other answers in this thread, I end up with

```
select 
  name, type 
from 
  mysql.proc 
where 
  db = database() 
order by 
  type, name;
```

... which ends you up with results that look like this:

```
mysql> select name, type from mysql.proc where db = database() order by type, name;
+------------------------------+-----------+
| name                         | type      |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| get_oldest_to_scan           | FUNCTION  |
| get_language_prevalence      | PROCEDURE |
| get_top_repos_by_user        | PROCEDURE |
| get_user_language_prevalence | PROCEDURE |
+------------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

Answer (score 18):

Shows all the stored procedures:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

Shows all the functions:

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;
```

Shows the definition of the specified procedure:

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE [PROC_NAME];
```

Shows you all the procedures of the given database:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = '[db_name]';
```

Answer (score 15):

use this:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

Answer (score 9):

A variation on Praveenkumar_V's post:

```
SELECT `name` FROM mysql.proc WHERE db = 'dbname' AND `type` = 'PROCEDURE';
SELECT `name` FROM mysql.proc WHERE db = 'dbname' AND `type` = 'FUNCTION';
```

..and this because I needed to save time after some housekeeping:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
     "GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `"
    ,`name`
    ,"` TO username@'%'; -- "
    ,`comment`
)
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE db = 'dbname'
AND `type` = 'PROCEDURE';

SELECT CONCAT(
     "GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION `"
    ,`name`
    ,"` TO username@'%'; -- "
    ,`comment`
)
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE db = 'dbname'
AND `type` = 'FUNCTION';
```

Answer (score 8):

To show just yours:

```
SELECT
  db, type, specific_name, param_list, returns
FROM
  mysql.proc
WHERE
  definer LIKE
  CONCAT('%', CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT user()), '@', 1)), '%'));
```

Comment: It's common convention to put SQL keywords in all caps, while putting column names, table names, etc in lower case.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT specific_name FROM `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` WHERE routine_schema='database_name'
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to list Store Procedure for Current Selected Database,

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = DATABASE();
```

it will list Routines based on current selected Database

**UPDATED**
to list out functions in your database

```
select * from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_SCHEMA="YOUR DATABASE NAME" and ROUTINE_TYPE="FUNCTION";
```

to list out routines/store procedures in your database,

```
select * from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_SCHEMA="YOUR DATABASE NAME" and ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE";
```

to list tables in your database,

```
select * from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE" AND TABLE_SCHEMA="YOUR DATABASE NAME";
```

to list views in your database,

**method 1:**

```
select * from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE="VIEW" AND TABLE_SCHEMA="YOUR DATABASE NAME";
```

**method 2:**

```
select * from information_schema.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="YOUR DATABASE NAME";
```

Answer (score 6):

As of MySQL 8.0, the `mysql.procs` table has been removed. Running any of the commands from answers here that use this table will yield you an error that says (quite logically):

```
Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

Instead, to retrieve a list of only the names of procedures/functions, use:

```
SELECT specific_name FROM `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` WHERE routine_schema='<your_db_name>';
```

In my case, I edited it to show only the procedures and not the functions:

```
SELECT specific_name FROM `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` WHERE routine_schema='<your_db_name>' AND routine_type='PROCEDURE';
```

Comment: Thank you for the MySQL 8.0 versions. Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

My favorite rendering of the procedures list of the current database: name, parameters list, comment

```
SELECT specific_name AS name, param_list AS params, `comment`
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE db = DATABASE()
AND type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

Add returns for functions:

```
SELECT specific_name AS name, param_list AS params, `returns`, `comment`
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE db = DATABASE()
AND type = 'FUNCTION';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                           show procedure status;
```

using this command you can see the all procedures in databases

Answer (score 0):

List **user's** procedures and functions for **all databases**:

```
SELECT 
    `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` AS `database`
    ,`ROUTINE_TYPE` AS `type`
    ,`SPECIFIC_NAME` AS `name`
    ,`DTD_IDENTIFIER` AS `data_type`
FROM 
    `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES`
WHERE
  `definer` LIKE
  CONCAT('%', CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT user()), '@', 1)), '%'))
ORDER BY
    `database`
    ,`type`
    ,`name`
;
```

List **user's** procedures and functions for the **database in use**:

```
SELECT 
    `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` AS `database`
    ,`ROUTINE_TYPE` AS `type`
    ,`SPECIFIC_NAME` AS `name`
    ,`DTD_IDENTIFIER` AS `data_type`
FROM 
    `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES`
WHERE
  `definer` LIKE
  CONCAT('%', CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT user()), '@', 1)), '%'))
AND
   `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
    `type`
    ,`name`
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show all functions with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-function-status.html) explains `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS` and I recommend to use [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) which can show them more clearly and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/show-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line/77546278#77546278) explains how to show procedures in MySQL:

```sql
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS\G
```

And, you can show the functions of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'apple'\G
```

And, you can show all functions with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html) explains `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'\G
```

And, you can show the functions of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'apple'\G
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show all procedures with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-status.html) explains `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` and I recommend to use [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) which can show them more clearly and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/show-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line/77546241#77546241) explains how to show functions in MySQL:

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS\G
```

And, you can show the procedures of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'apple'\G
```

And, you can show all procedures with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html) explains `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'\G
```

And, you can show the functions of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'apple'\G
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following query for all the procedures:

```
select * from sysobjects 
where type='p'
order by crdate desc
```