# How to list mysql stored procedure parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What is the SQL to list the parameters of a MySQL stored procdure? The `information_schema.routines` table holds the stored procedure names but there doesn't seem to be a standard place where the parameters are stored.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line.  Not sure you can isolate the parameters without the body text

Comment: Which version are you using? Newer versions have information_schema.parameters. In older versions, look at mysql.proc - column paramlist (although they aren't in a great format!)

Comment: @dash bang on, don't know how I missed that table. I'm using 5.5.9. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More recent versions of MySQL ([5.5.3 and above](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/parameters-table.html)) introduced the information_schema.parameters object which should give you the information you need;

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.parameters 
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'your_procedure';
```

Earlier versions of MySql rely on having access to the mysql.proc table; the column 'param_list' has all of the parameter information in there for the procedure with the name you are interested in. The information is decidedly non-normalised, though, as it is stored as comma separated string:

```
SELECT param_list FROM mysql.proc WHERE db='your_database' AND name='your_procedure';
```

Gives:

```
IN param1 VARCHAR(32), IN param2 int, ...
```

This requires some more work to put into a format for presentation; although a string.split function would at least tidy it up.

Answer (score 1):

`show create procedure` `show create function`? these inbound calls require 
the access to the `mysql.proc` table that's where you have to look at 
and the `body` field is of `longblob` type there
`select cast(param_list as char) from mysql.proc where name='' and type='PROCEDURE'`

Comment: `mysql.proc` table was removed in MySQL 8.0. see https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure that returns a list of parameters in the table. It may be useful to someone.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Micropsitta.'getParams'(parname varchar(255)) 
    BEGIN
    set @wyraz=(select cast(param_list as char)
    from mysql.proc 
    where type='PROCEDURE'  
    and name COLLATE utf8_polish_ci = parname COLLATE utf8_polish_ci);
    drop TEMPORARY table if exists tab;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tab (substrings varchar(255)) ENGINE=MEMORY;
    IF ((@wyraz) <> '')
     THEN
     set @firstchar=1;
     set @spacje=1;
     set @lenghtWyraz=(select CHAR_LENGTH(@wyraz));
     set @lenght=1;
     while @lenght < @lenghtWyraz
     DO
      set @lenght=(select CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@wyraz,' ',@spacje)));
      set @sub=(select SUBSTRING(@wyraz,@firstchar,@lenght-@firstchar+1));
      set @firstchar=(select CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@wyraz,',',@spacje)))+2;
      insert into tab (substrings)
      select @sub;
      set @spacje=@spacje+1;
     end while;
    END IF;
    select substrings as params from tab where substrings <>'';
    END;
```