# Is there a statement or call in MySQL to get details about a Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Specifically, I'd like to be able to make some kind of call to find out how many IN parameters are required for the sproc, their variable names, and their types.

Here's some pseudocode to show basically what I'd like to get:

```
DETAILS Add_Item() IN
```

And it would return something like:

```
Username VARCHAR(100)
Title VARCHAR(255)
Discs INT(3)
```

Is anything like that possible from within MySQL? Or are sprocs simply just black boxes that you can only view the details of when creating/modifying them?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.parameters 
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'Add_Item'
```

Duplicate of: [How to list mysql stored procedure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546378/how-to-list-mysql-stored-procedure-parameters)

Please close the question.