# Why I obtain this error when I try to create this funcion (that use point data type) on a MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysql-spatial

I am not so into database and I have the following doubt implementing this tutorial: https://mariadb.org/jquery-and-gis-distance-in-mariadb/

So basically my doubt is relate to this SQL statment that create a function to calculate the distance between two **point** on a MariaDB database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION earth_circle_distance(point1 point, point2 point) RETURNS double
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
  declare lon1, lon2 double;
  declare lat1, lat2 double;
  declare td double;
  declare d_lat double;
  declare d_lon double;
  declare a, c, R double;

  set lon1 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lon2 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));
  set lat1 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lat2 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));

  set d_lat = radians(lat2 - lat1);
  set d_lon = radians(lon2 - lon1);

  set lat1 = radians(lat1);
  set lat2 = radians(lat2);

  set R = 6372.8; -- in kilometers

  set a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) * sin(d_lat / 2.0) + sin(d_lon / 2.0) * sin(d_lon / 2.0) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
  set c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));

  return R * c;
end
```

My problem is that performing the previous statment I obtain the following error message:

```
Error
----------------------------------------------------
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.
    1. Unrecognized data type. (near "point" at position 45)
    2. Unrecognized data type. (near "point" at position 59)

SQL query:

CREATE FUNCTION earth_circle_distance(point1 point, point2 point) RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC begin declare lon1, lon2 double 

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

**PhpMyAdmin** sign with 2 red marker the **point** data type on the first line of the previous statment:

```
CREATE FUNCTION earth_circle_distance(point1 point, point2 point) RETURNS double
```

but I don't think that it could be the real problem (I think that maybe is something that **PhpMyAdmin** don't know) because it mark red also this cration query:

```
CREATE TABLE gis_point  (g POINT);
```

but it works fine, give me no error and correctly create the table.

So, whta is wrong? Could depend by **PhpMyAdmin** or what am I missing?
Where this function should be stored?

Comment: It is important to change the delimiter in MySQL. Otherwise the function definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete. Add `delimiter ||` before the function definition and a `||` after the function definition

Comment: @juergend what exactly have I to do? How is it possible? The example is taken directly from the MariaDB website

Comment: So you have taken another step backwards?

Comment: @e4c5 no I am only trying to perfrom this statment into my DB to create this funcion

Comment: @juergend Where have I to put this delimeter? Please can you give me a complete response showing me the code? So I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the delimiter. Otherwise the function definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.

```
delimiter ||
CREATE FUNCTION earth_circle_distance(point1 point, point2 point) RETURNS double
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
  declare lon1, lon2 double;
  declare lat1, lat2 double;
  declare td double;
  declare d_lat double;
  declare d_lon double;
  declare a, c, R double;

  set lon1 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lon2 = X(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));
  set lat1 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point1)));
  set lat2 = Y(GeomFromText(AsText(point2)));

  set d_lat = radians(lat2 - lat1);
  set d_lon = radians(lon2 - lon1);

  set lat1 = radians(lat1);
  set lat2 = radians(lat2);

  set R = 6372.8; -- in kilometers

  set a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) * sin(d_lat / 2.0) + sin(d_lon / 2.0) * sin(d_lon / 2.0) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
  set c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));

  return R * c;
end
||

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine, the function is now create. A last dout: where this funcion is stored? How can I see it in my DB? (for example using PhpMyAdmin)

Comment: I don't use phpMyAdmin. But I am sure you can google that

Comment: It is stored in the database.  Do you want the filename?  Or what?  You can see it in `information_schema.ROUTINES`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line