# MySQL - CREATE DEFINER syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a stored function in our MySQL database. The update is to be released to multiple devices so I am doing it through an update.sql file.

Here is the function

```
DROP FUNCTION `STAFF_MPT`;
CREATE DEFINER=`jelena`@`%` FUNCTION `STAFF_MPT`(`par_stocktake_staff_id`     INT) RETURNS DECIMAL(20,0) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN

DECLARE proc_total INT;
DECLARE proc_time INT;

SET proc_total = (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stocktake_scans WHERE stocktake_staff_id = par_stocktake_staff_id);

SET proc_time = (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND , MIN( scan_date ) , MAX( scan_date ) ) AS area_time
    FROM stocktake_scans
    WHERE stocktake_staff_id = par_stocktake_staff_id
    );

RETURN (proc_total/proc_time)*3600;

END
```

It was just reported to me by the test team that the report that uses this function did not generate properly. I tried to run the code in PMA SQL query window and got the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing? According to this, line 3 is empty, so how could it possibly have a syntax error?

Comment: You forgot the delimiter. See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40467504/575376

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the `delimiter` command.

@juergen_d hinted in the comment: you have to define your procedure with a delimiter:

```
DROP FUNCTION `STAFF_MPT`;

delimiter ||

CREATE DEFINER=`jelena`@`%` FUNCTION `STAFF_MPT`(`par_stocktake_staff_id`     INT) RETURNS DECIMAL(20,0) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN

DECLARE proc_total INT;
DECLARE proc_time INT;

SET proc_total = (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stocktake_scans WHERE stocktake_staff_id = par_stocktake_staff_id);

SET proc_time = (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND , MIN( scan_date ) , MAX( scan_date ) ) AS area_time
    FROM stocktake_scans
    WHERE stocktake_staff_id = par_stocktake_staff_id
    );

RETURN (proc_total/proc_time)*3600;

END

||
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to put in the delimiter after the drop function part, but it does work now :)

Comment: oh yes, you're right, it had to be after the `drop` call. I fixed it.

Comment: I'm being picky now, but also a space here delimiter; then you're answer is 101%