# Total count of stored procedures in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How to get the total count of stored procedures in a MySQL database? Do I look in the information schema?

Comment: Yes you should check `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Specifically check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36700359/643104)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Stored Procedures/Functions Mysql Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line)

Comment: Total? For all users, or just the stored procedures you have access to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this to see the list of Procedures

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE" 
AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="dbname";
```

You can find out more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html)

Comment: All routines, or just the ones current user has access to?

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution, just replace your database name in the last line.

```
SELECT count(ROUTINE_NAME)procedure_count
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE" 
AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="your database name";
```

Comment: An explanation of your code is always needed, as others should be able to learn from your code. Additionally, please don't be rude

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SELECT     
    COUNT(*) as 'Stored Procedures'     
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE ='P'
GROUP BY TYPE
```