# Mysql: Find all stored procedures that reference a specific table

Tags: mysql

I want to check all SPs/function that reference a particular table in mysql. I found a query which I belive is to check the same in sql server:

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%tablename%'
```

But in mysql it says 'Table sys.procedures doesn't exist'

Comment: Oh wait. This is for MSSQL, but you're working on MySQL?

Comment: yes. i want query in mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Stored Procedures/Functions Mysql Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line)

Answer (score 10):

```
select * from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%tableName%';
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to query `Mysql.proc` table, [here's](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlproc-table/) the documentation:

> The mysql.proc table contains information about stored procedures and
>   stored functions. It contains similar information to that stored in
>   the INFORMATION SCHEMA.ROUTINES table.

Your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Mysql.proc
WHERE type = 'PROCEDURE'
AND body LIKE '%tablename%';
```